# Search Android app by part of package name

Tags: android

I want to search all the applications created by me with a definite package structure.

For example - say my package structure initial is my.android.puzzle.xxx

Now value for 'xxx' can be anything.

I want to search all apps with initial package structure as my.android.puzzle

Can anyone tell me how to do this.

Comment: Are you just searching for files or files containing certain words?  How about grep?

Comment: Do you want to do it from a computer console or from another application? If first, try `adb shell pm list packages | grep puzzle`

Comment: First you need to fetch the package name of all the installed applications in the device and then you can perform your search as usual.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here is a nice code snippet given to [Get installed Applications with Name, Package Name, Version and Icon](http://www.androidsnippets.com/get-installed-applications-with-name-package-name-version-and-icon). Now review this code and try to implement the code for your requirement: Fetch all package names. After done with package name getting, just implement the search functionality as we implement for the string inner search.

Comment: Also for the help of others, below code opens a app from other app

Intent i = new Intent(Intent.ACTION_MAIN);
PackageManager manager = getPackageManager();
i = manager.getLaunchIntentForPackage("app package name");
i.addCategory(Intent.CATEGORY_LAUNCHER);
startActivity(i);